# php Fatal error: Call to a member function

Tags: php, function

My code is :

```
<?php

require('soap_config.php');

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $soap_location,
                                     'uri'      => $soap_uri,
                                     'trace' => 1,
                                     'exceptions' => 1));

try {
    if($session_id = $client->login($username,$password)) {
        echo 'Logged successfull. Session ID:'.$session_id.'<br />';
    }

    //* Set the function parameters.
    $client_id = 2;

    function ftpadduser()
    {

        $params = array(
                        'server_id' => 1,
                        'parent_domain_id' => 1,
                        'username' => 'threep',
                        'password' => 'wood',
                        'quota_size' => 10,
                        'active' => 'y',
                        'uid' => '5000',
                        'gid' => '5000',
                        'dir' => 'maybe',
                        'quota_files' => -1,
                        'ul_ratio' => -1,
                        'dl_ratio' => -1,
                        'ul_bandwidth' => -1,
                        'dl_bandwidth' => -1
                        );

        $affected_rows = $client->sites_ftp_user_add($session_id,$client_id, $params);

        echo "FTP User ID: ".$affected_rows."<br>";

    }

    ftpadduser();

    if($client->logout($session_id)) {
        echo 'Logged out.<br />';
    }


} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $client->__getLastResponse();
    die('SOAP Error: '.$e->getMessage());
  }

?>
```

and although I am able to run everything if I don't use function somehow in this case it gives me

```
Logged successfull. Session ID:9a46b41e293ff9d5d5604648013caf76

Fatal error: Call to a member function sites_ftp_user_add() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\client_get.php on line 39
```

as output and I wonder if anyone can help me how I can run this function and avoid the fatal error.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple scoping issue. `$client` is not in the `ftpadduser()` function

Comment: Also, you might as well just unwrap the `ftpadduser` function (ie, remove `function ftpadduser() {` and the closing `}`). It is completely redundant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you explicitly declare them as `global`, references to a variable inside a function are local.

You have initialised $client, but not passed it into your `ftpadduser()` function, so your method call doesn't see the correct value and fails.

There are other variables you also need that haven't been passed in. Decllare your function like this:

```
function ftpadduser($client, $session_id, $client_id) {
    //your code
 }
```

Then call it with `ftpadduser($client, $session_id, $client_id);`

Comment: yep, just declare as this: function ftpadduser($client)(line:17) and call ftpadduser($client);(line 43)